# Aliases removed across multiple classes

Tags: google-classroom

We create classes for multiple school districts via googles classroom api. We noticed that on 2017-12-18 we had multiple classes have their Aliases removed (We ended up creating duplicate classes as we use this alias for our unique ID). We use a domain-scoped alias as defined here https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.aliases

Any ideas? I'll keep this updated as we find more information.

Comment: Bug submitted here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71326131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google found the root cause on their end. This was a google issue.

Note: I did remove some of the messages from google but nothing context related just some specific things about questions related to our company.

> Hello *****,
>
> I hope this message finds you well. This is a follow up message
>   concerning your case with Google Cloud Support.
>
> I would like to inform you that we just received an update from our
>   Engineering Team regarding the bug that was affecting the Classroom
>   Aliases. According to the update received, our Engineering Team was
>   able to identify the root cause of the issue and the issue is now
>   fully resolved. This means that the aliases will no longer clear when
>   making update to the courses via API. I possible, we would like to
>   know if you are still seeing aliases that are deleted or seemingly
>   disappearing?
>
> According to the information and due to the nature of this bug, our
>   Engineering Team will not be able to restore the previously deleted
>   aliases but they are working on creating an alternative solution in
>   case anyone else encounters this issue in the future. This means that
>   they will have a way to recover aliases in the future in case they are
>   deleted by a bug or issue in our end. Please rest assured that this
>   API issue should not occur again but if it does, we will have a way to
>   get those aliases restored.
>
> I suggest that you recreate the aliases, test to see if there is any
>   other issues and let me know if you need any additional help or if you
>   have any questions regarding the above response. Again, we really
>   appreciate your patience and continued support while we work to
>   identify the root cause of this issue.
>
> The best way to reach or API Team is by opening a support case and
>   wait for us to reply back via email or wait for a call back. We will
>   normally sent an email requesting the best time and phone number to
>   contact you back. You can also reply to any of our cases during a
>   period of 30 days and your will be be reopened and I will be able to
>   contact you back as soon as possible.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Google Cloud Support